# Log4j Validating if Exception is passed as last argument

Tags: java, java-8, log4j, slf4j

I am using slf4j with log4j. My POM dependency looks like below -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

As mentioned in [SLF4J FAQ](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException)

> The SLF4J API supports parametrization in the presence of an
>   exception, assuming the exception is the last parameter.

In a is there a way to identify if exception is passed as a last argument to all logger's method call (like `error`, `info`)?

Comment: You're the one who passes it using the api for example -> 
   `} catch (Exception e) {
    String message = "This is an example";
    logger.error(message, e);
   }`

Comment: Yes. I am working on a legacy code base which is quite big. So I am looking for a way to identify optimally if there are any logger call in which Exception is not passed as a last argument. I hope I am clear what I am trying to ask. Basically I am looking for a way to validate the logger's call for semantics.

Comment: Validate it where? In your IDE?

Comment: I want the list of offending methods if any. If it can be done in IDE then even better. .

Comment: You probably have calls that don't have an exception (especially for info level and below) so you'd certainly want to check instead that, if there is an exception: 1. it is the last argument and 2. the number of parameters excl. the exception matches the provided message. It seems [findbugs-slf4j](https://github.com/KengoTODA/findbugs-slf4j) would do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this kind of check at compile time, or even at runtime.

You can however use a combination of [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and the [findbugs-slf4j](https://github.com/KengoTODA/findbugs-slf4j) plugin to check this statically with [`SLF4J_PLACE_HOLDER_MISMATCH`](https://github.com/KengoTODA/findbugs-slf4j#slf4j_place_holder_mismatch) and `SLF4J_FORMAT_SHOULD_BE_CONST`.